# How to make a group of databases

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, grouping

I am experiencing a problem with grouping databases !

Databases

1. lbsinsti_lbs
2. lbsinsti_mera,
3. lbsinsti_merabachpan,
4. lbsinti_school,
5. lbsinsti_vijayvergiya,
6. lbsinsti_vvbv

I want these databases to be grouped in a single directory or folder

But now It's showing the all 5 databases in the main directory.
Please Help! 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so phpMyAdmin should be set to do this automatically, I have tried placing your specific tables in my own phpMyAdmin and the grouping worked correctly.

What version of phpMyAdmin do you have? Have you manipulated the config file at all?

Try going into the settings of phpMyAdmin to see if this particular setting is enabled: settings -> navigation panel -> uncheck/check "group items in tree"

Or go straight to the **config.inc.php** which can be found in your xampp/phpMyAdmin folder and check to see what this line of code is set to:

```
$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = false;
```

Obviously if this is set to false your grouping will not work, in your case you will want this set to true.